# How to pass in an object to a Xamarin Forms custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I pass an instance of some object, to a Xamarin Forms `custom render`?

this is the custom renderer...

```cs
public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

and this is what I want to do.... (notice the ctor has been added ...)

```cs
public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private SomeFoo _someFoo;

    public LoginPageRenderer(MyFoo someFoo)
    {
        _someFoo = someFoo;
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Finally, this is where this view is called (in some other part of the code).

`await _navigationPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define a publicly accessible property in your `LoginPage` object you can reference it in the `Renderer` using `Element.NameOfYourProperty` syntax.

#### Update by PureKrome

Sample code ...

***LoginPage.cs*** (in your PCL common project).

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly Foo _foo;

        public LoginPage(Foo foo)
        {
            _foo = foo;
        }

        public Foo Foo { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

***LoginPageRenderer.cs*** (in your iOS project)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (LoginPage), typeof (LoginPageRenderer))]

namespace Foo.iOS
{
    public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private Foo Foo
        {
            get
            {
                var loginPage = Element as LoginPage;
                return loginPage == null
                    ? null
                    : loginPage.Foo; 
            }
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Foo.SecretName))
            { ... }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a `static public property`? Which is not really what I'm hoping is the answer - I hate using statics and try and avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Nope. Just cast the Element property in the Renderer as a LoginPage and you can access your property in a non-static manner.

Comment: OMG. that ... worked! I've never ever read anything about this `Element` property and how it's accessible in the renderer, etc.

Comment: Glad to help! It's not very well documented unless you're digging into sample code. Let me know if you ever need more info.

Comment: i've updated your answer with some code .. can u just review it to make sure it's on target with your thinking.

Comment: Close, but you might want to call the LoginPage Property in the Renderer something other than "Settings".

Comment: It's a bit confusing since the LoginPage itself has a "Settings" property as well. Just a thought.

Comment: Can you mark as selected answer when you get a chance?

Comment: Thanks for this useful advice @deckertron_9000 !